# Problem while executing code including custom transformers?

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, data-science

While working on California Housing Dataset through Aurelian Gideon's book of O'Reilly publication, in the Custom Transformers section, I ran the code below :-

```
from sklearn.base import BaseEstimator, TransformerMixin 
rooms_ix, bedrooms_ix, population_ix, households_ix = 3, 4, 5, 6

class CombinedAttributesAdder(BaseEstimator, TransformerMixin): 
    def __init__(self, add_bedrooms_per_room = True): # no *args or **kargs 
        self.add_bedrooms_per_room = add_bedrooms_per_room
    def fit(self, X, y=None): 
        return self # nothing else to do
    def transform(self, X, y=None): 
        rooms_per_household = X[:, rooms_ix] / X[:, households_ix] 
        population_per_household = X[:, population_ix] / X[:, households_ix] 
        if self.add_bedrooms_per_room: 
            bedrooms_per_room = X[:, bedrooms_ix] / X[:, rooms_ix] 
            return np.c_[X, rooms_per_household, population_per_household, bedrooms_per_room]
    else: 
        return np.c_[X, rooms_per_household, population_per_household]
    
attr_adder = CombinedAttributesAdder(add_bedrooms_per_room=False) 
housing_extra_attribs = attr_adder.transform(housing.values)
```

The error I get is as follows:-

```
File "<ipython-input-43-43e04d49480a>", line 16
    return np.c_[X, rooms_per_household, population_per_household]
    ^
IndentationError: expected an indented block
```

Please suggest how to fix it?

Comment: Your `else` is outside the function.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

housing.values is a function

You should use its "data" to perform transform task.

such as

```py
housing["data"]
```